# Forget password form in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to implement forget password form in my asp.net mvc 4 project, everything works fine, but when I try to login to system with new password it told me that I have wrong password.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ForgetPassword(UserViewModel userModel) {
    const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    var random = new Random();
    var result = new string(
        Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 8)
                  .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                  .ToArray());

    User user = _userRepo.GetUserByEmail(userModel.Email);
    if (user == null) {
        ViewBag.Error = Resources.Account.userEmailNotExist;
        return View(userModel);
    }

    String newHashedPassword = Crypto.HashPassword(result);
    user.Password = newHashedPassword;
    user.LastPasswordChangedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    _userRepo.SaveChanges();

    string enMessage = "Your new password: " + result;

    var httpCookie = Request.Cookies["lang"];
    if (httpCookie != null && httpCookie.Value == "en") {
        _mailHelper.SendEmail(userModel.Email, "New password", enMessage);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("ConfirmPasswordChange", "Account");
}
```

Login form:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(UserViewModel user) {
    var users = _userRepo.GetAllEntitiesWithParam("JobsDb_Users_GetByEmail", user.Email).FirstOrDefault();
    ...
    try {
        var tryLogin = WebSecurity.Login(users.Username, user.Password, true);
        if (tryLogin == WebSecurity.MembershipLoginStatus.Failure)
        {
            var httpCookie = Request.Cookies["lang"];
            if (httpCookie != null && httpCookie.Value == "en") {
                ViewBag.Error = "Your password is incorrect.";
                new SeoHelper().ReturnSeoTags(this, "Login");
            }
            return View(user);
        }
        ...
    } catch {
        ...
    }
}
```

inside WebSecurity

```
public static MembershipLoginStatus Login(string username, string password, bool rememberMe) {
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password)) {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, rememberMe);
        return MembershipLoginStatus.Success;
    } else {
        return MembershipLoginStatus.Failure;
    }
}
```

inside Membership

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) {
        return false;
    }
    User user = _userRepository.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(usr => usr.Username == username);
    if (user == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!user.IsApproved.Value) {
        return false;
    }
    if (user.IsLockedOut.Value) {
        return false;
    }
    String hashedPassword = user.Password;
    Boolean verificationSucceeded = (hashedPassword != null && Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(hashedPassword, password));
    if (verificationSucceeded) { //here is I have false if try to login using password from forget form
        user.PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess = 0;
        user.LastLoginDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        user.LastActivityDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    } else {
        int failures = user.PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess.Value;
        if (failures < MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts) {
            user.PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess += 1;
            user.LastPasswordFailureDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        } else if (failures >= MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts) {
            user.LastPasswordFailureDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            user.LastLockoutDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            user.IsLockedOut = true;
        }
    }
    _userRepository.SaveChanges();
    if (verificationSucceeded) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your login method ?

Comment: @ByteBlast register method work, I'm override standart methods because I need to customize my user table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step is to open up your database and verify that the new password was actually persisted. If it has, the most likely cause is that your repository is working with stale (cached) data.

If you're using Entity Framework, this happens because the framework will, by default, cache the state of the database at the time the DbContext is created, so it is retaining your original password. You can verify this by logging in with the original password.

Comment: I have a generic repository and yes my new hashed password is successfully changed.

Comment: @BorHunter So, what ultimately calls into your database, in the repository? ADO.NET? Some variation of nHibernate?

Comment: EF, I guess this is not a problem with updating entries, this is some problems with checking or generating hash passwords.

Comment: Assuming by "Membership" that you're using a MembershipProvider of one sort or another, your repository only gets created once, since MembershipProviders are rather long-lived. You can test this by modifying your `ValidateUser` to use a brand new repo every time it's called.

Comment: dont understand what do you mean

Comment: I was check one more time with debugger and you're right, my password isn't updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but following code does not look right to me:

```
    User user = _userRepo.GetUserByEmail(userModel.Email);
    if (user == null) {
        ViewBag.Error = Resources.Account.userEmailNotExist;
        return View(userModel);
    }

    String newHashedPassword = Crypto.HashPassword(result);
    user.Password = newHashedPassword;
    user.LastPasswordChangedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    _userRepo.SaveChanges();
```

You fetched the user from repository, make changes to user object in memory and then called SaveChanges() on the repository. Does that work in your world? How does `_userRepo.SaveChanges();` knows which object has changed. Do you see correct hashed value in DB after the call? What value you see in ValidateUser() method for password? Is the hashing algorithm consistent both while generating hashed password and while verifying?

I could be wrong, if that's the case it will be good if you share little bit more of analysis around the question I asked above.

Comment: I'm using generic repo and yes it's work in my world. After save my hashed value in db is changed.

Comment: `Crypto.HashPassword` and `Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword` are both members of the Crypto class, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto%28v=vs.111%29.aspx, so yes; essentially, PBKDF2.